After defining $n_j := \min \left\{n > n_{j-1} : |a_n - L| \leq \frac{1}{j} \right\}$, what do I need to show about $n_j$?
The following is a result from Analysis I, Terence Tao, Third Edition (Proposition 6.6.6/Exercise 6.6.5):

Let $(a_n)_{n=0}^\infty$ be a sequence of real numbers, and let $L$ be a real number. Then the following two statements are logically equivalent.
(a) $L$ is a limit point of $(a_n)_{n=0}^\infty$.
(b) There exists a subsequence of $(a_n)_{n=0}^\infty$ which converges to $L$.

In proving that (a) implies (b), I used Tao's suggestion to define the numbers $n_j$ for each natural number $j$ by the formula:
$$
n_j := \min \left\{n > n_{j-1} : |a_n - L| \leq \frac{1}{j} \right\}
$$
with the convention that $n_0 := 0$. Tao suggested to first show that the set in the $\min$ argument is non-empty, and then to consider the sequence $a_{n_j}$. I have done both and was able to show the subsequence defined by $b_j = a_{n_j}$ converges to $L$, but I have the following questions:
(1) Do I have to show that $n_j$ is a function?
(2) Do I need to show that $n_j$ is well-defined as a function? What I mean is, do I have to show that if $j = k$, then $n_j = n_k$?
(3) Do I need to show that $n_j$ is an increasing function of $j$?

The sequence of indices ${n_j}_j$ corresponds to the subsequence you extract in order to prove (b). I am not sure what you means by (1). For (2) you can show this is the case by the definition of $n_j$. For (3) it also follows from the definition.

Formally, yes. But the points you mention are rather trivial.
(1, 2) With the understanding that you are considering $n: \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$ as defined by $n (j) = n_j$, this follows from the fact that

The $\min$ argument is non-empty for any $j \in \mathbb{N} - \{ 0 \}$, which you mentioned you have already shown.
We show that $n$ is well-defined by induction. For the base case, $n (0) = 0$. For the inductive step, assume that $n (k)$ is well-defined for $k \in \mathbb{N}$; we show $n (k + 1)$ is well-defined. For this, we can use the fact that the standard order on $\mathbb{N}$ is a well-order, so that the $\min$ argument (which is a nonempty subset of $\mathbb{N}$) has a unique smallest element. Then $n (k + 1)$ is equal to this element.

(3) Fix $j \in \mathbb{N}$; we claim that $n (k) > n (j)$ for all $k \in \{ j + 1, \dots \}$. This can be done by induction. For the base case, we have by the definition of $n$ that $n (j + 1) > n (j)$. For the inductive step, suppose that $n (k) > n (j)$ for $k \in \{ j + 1, \dots \}$. Since by definition of $n$, we have $n (k + 1) > n (k)$, then obviously $n (k + 1) > n (j)$. Since $j$ was arbitrary, this completes the proof that $n$ is an increasing function.
Edit: Some additional comments.
If we want to be even more explicit for point (2), suppose that $n: \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$ satisfies the given criteria, namely,
$$n (j) = \begin{cases}
0 & j = 0 \\
\min \left\{ n > n (j - 1) | d (a_n, L) < \frac{1}{j} \right\} & \text{otherwise} \\
\end{cases}$$
To show that $n$ is well-defined; i.e., that $j = k \implies n (j) = n (k)$, we proceed using induction. For the base case $j = k = 0$, we have that $n (j) = n (k) = 0$ by definition. Now, suppose that $n (j) = n (k)$ for $j = k$; we show that $n (j + 1) = n (k + 1)$. By definition,
$$n (j + 1) = \min \underbrace{\left\{ n > n (j) | d (a_n, L) < \frac{1}{j + 1} \right\}}$$
As I mentioned above, the underbraced item, being a non-empty subset of $\mathbb{N}$, is well-ordered in the standard order. Therefore, it possesses a unique smallest element, which is defined to be $n (j + 1)$. Note that because $j = k$ and $n (j) = n (k)$, the underbraced set is precisely equal to
$$\left\{ n > n (k) | d (a_n, L) < \frac{1}{k + 1} \right\}$$
which confirms that $n (j + 1) = n (k + 1)$.

Thank you! Although I'm not sure how your argument for showing it's well-defined is similar to what I have suggested showing.

@PaulAsh No problem. I've updated my answer; please see if you are convinced now.

Perfect! I appreciate you showing it more explicitly. Thanks again.
